# How do I stop the SVN window from opening on Eclipse startup?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As best as I know, I don't need the svn add-on, yet it keeps opening a window on eclipse startup asking for me to choose which svn I want to use. I close the window without cheking any options, and all is well. But this window is very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what has happened is that you have somehow installed the Subversive plugin (maybe it is included in your Eclipse distro by default somehow).  The Subversive plugin requires an additional feature to be installed, and that feature is the actual SVN libraries to use.  You have a choice of SVN libraries and that is what the dialog is likely asking you to install.

See here for a detailed description:
http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php#svncon

You have 2 choices:

1. Install a subversion connector and the dialog will never come up again.  This will not harm your system and one day if you choose to use SVN, you will already have the plugin configured.
2. Uninstall subversive.  Go to: Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details.  Scroll down to the Subversive entries.  Select them all and click "Uninstall".

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the addon.

*Help → Install New Software → What is already installed? →* [uninstall your SVN plugin here]

Comment: Or About Eclipse -> Installation Details ->  [uninstall your SVN plugin here]

Comment: @PaulB: you're right. The extra clicks are darn annoying, but then again Eclipse doesn't win too many awards for UX.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes even though you uninstall subversion, there are still some plugins related to SVN that remaining. You can see them in `[Installation details -> Plugins]`.

Go to your eclipse installation folder (e.g. *`C:\Eclipse on windows`*, *`/Applications/Eclipse`* on Mac OS X) then plugins folder and remove every file starting with "`org.eclipse.team.svn`"

You can see the list of the files that need to be removed from Plugins section of Installation details.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a fake one and see if it goes away? :)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Tim it's not really a comment - it's an answer that may or may not solve the problem. Is it my best answer ever? No, no it's not. If I really wanted to round out the answer, I could have set up a new install of Eclipse, tried to recreate the problem, and then tested it to see if it worked. But I didn't do that. I have a strong hunch it will work. But it might not. In any event, this isn't what a comment is for. If you feel my answer is not useful, there's a downvote button just up and to the left of here. I feel it has potential usefulness, which is why I've left it here.